# How can I export Mdaemon filter rules

Tags: migration, imap, zimbra, rules, mdaemon

I'm now migrating my Mdaemon Mail Server to a Zimbra Server. I can export the account list, synchronize the mail data via IMAP. But I dont know how to export the IMAP filter rules of each Mdaemon account and import to Zimbra Filter

Anybody knows how to do that?

Comment: Anybody gives me some advices :(

Answer (score 0):

After digging hours in Mdaemon folder, I found that it write the rules to HIWATER.MRK in Users folder. Can't believe it, i had checked that file and not scrolled to the end to see the Rules lines, arrrrrrrrghhhhhhhhhhhh!